# What is the best way for a shared database to have a multi-user login that only shows the records of logged in user?

Tags: ms-access

Using MS-Access 2016 I have database in a shared location. 
Background on my database: 
I have a user login where they enter the information. Example: User1 is logged in. 
User1 can enter records and edit their own records. 
At the same time User1 is logged in, User2 also logs in. 
How can I have it so User1 can only see their own records and User2 only see their own records?

Comment: Record the UserId when saving a record. Filter on the UserId when displaying records.

Comment: @Gustav my issue is that I have the UserID stored in another table (currentUser) but every time someone else logs in it replaces the info in (currentUser) so it won't filter properly.

Comment: The current user must be that of the current session, not the user storing something latest -that would be something like "LastUser".

Comment: @Gustav Do you know how I would be able to separate each individual so nothing overlaps when multiple people are logged into the database at once?

Comment: Yes - that was my first comment (though not quite sure what you mean with _overlaps_).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multi-user database should be split design. This means backend with data on file server and frontend links to tables in backend and is installed on each user computer. Login procedure saves UserID to a location that can be referenced when needed (not in linked backend table). Options are:

- textbox on form
- global variable
- TempVar
- table in frontend

I use textbox on form that never closes (MainMenu).

Comment: Thank you! You confirmed what I just did. Quick question, does the frontend HAVE to be on each users computer? I was hoping I could leave it on a server and have everyone use that one file.

Comment: Each user should run an independent copy of frontend to reduce chance of corruption. Conventional approach is to install on each user computer for best performance. Copies could be installed into user folders on server and run from there but performance may suffer. This is akin to each user having their own install of Word or Excel or Outlook or any application software. The Access database should be considered and treated as an application.

Comment: Ahhh, okay that makes sense. Thank you for your help!